# Git clone in script

Tags: linux, rvm

I am writing a bash script where I need to clone a git rep. How can I make it so that when this shows up, it automatically puts the value yes in ?

```
==============================================================================
= NOTICE                                                                     =
==============================================================================
= RVM has encountered a new or modified .rvmrc file in the current directory =
= This is a shell script and therefore may contain any shell commands.       =
=                                                                            =
= Examine the contents of this file carefully to be sure the contents are    =
= safe before trusting it! ( Choose v[iew] below to view the contents )      =
==============================================================================
Do you wish to trust this .rvmrc file? (/root/The-Three-Little-Pigs-Siri-Proxy/.rvmrc)
y[es], n[o], v[iew], c[ancel]>
```

Ubuntu 10.10 32 bit

Comment: What's RVM and why is it interfering with your git clone?

Comment: @GregHewgill - It's Ruby Version Manager. Probably the script clones and cds into it. That would trigger the rvm hook if the folder has a .rvmrc file. Anyway, removed git tag and added rvm.

Comment: Correct, the script clones then cds into it.

Comment: Would it be better to use the `linux` tag instead of `ubuntu`? Since the problem has nothing related to ubuntu-specific things.

Comment: I'll change it, I wasn't sure so I thought I would be as specific as I could

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file in your home directory, `.rvmrc` and add the following line to it:

```
rvm_trust_rvmrcs_flag=1
```

Or trust the file with:

```
rvm rvmrc trust /root/The-Three-Little-Pigs-Siri-Proxy/
```

Comment: /home or the directory that I'm cloning it into?

Comment: I think he means `/home/username`, or `~`

Answer (score 1):

You may look into [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).